# Tuning a script to grep the output of a curl

Tags: curl, grep

I am setting up a check to lookup a few words in a XML file generated from CURL statement and issue an alert if those words are not found.

```
curl -m 10 --header "Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8"  --data @payload.xml http://test.abc.com/services/Games  2>&1 | grep -iwn 'Game1\|Game2\|Game3'
```

Since the output of the **CURL** is an XML format I am using the `stdout` and using `grep` to find the 3 different game in that XML . This is printing out the XML as is and highlighting the games , for my alert what I want to do is if neither of these games are found in the curl output I need to send a notification out.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,
K

Answer (score 0):

Use command return code:

```
$ echo aaa | grep aaa
aaa
$ echo $?
0

$ echo bbb | grep aaa
$ echo $?
1
```

You may extend your command to send an email when `grep` return non-zero code:

```
curl -m 10 --header "Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8"  \
--data @payload.xml http://test.abc.com/services/Games 2>&1 \
| grep -iwn 'Game1\|Game2\|Game3' \
|| (echo | mail -s "Game not found" user@domain.com)
```